# Apple external (magic) keyboard: SHIFT + [ not working

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, usb, hardware, mac-pro

Im having some weird problem. I have connected my magic keyboard via USB.

When I type "`[`" its working as you see. Also when I type `SHIFT + ]` I get "`}`".

PROBLEM: But when I try to type `SHIFT + [` I cant get left curly bracket.
(Its working on my internal keyboard)

PRAM reseted. Keyboard layout - English. No shortcuts on this combinations made. Sticky keys OFF, slow keys OFF. Dictation OFF.

What could be the problem ? Maybe I could delete some Library/Preferences or something ? I cant code without that brackets

Comment: Do the key presses show up on the key caps / keyboard viewer? (You can start it from the internationalization menu)

Comment: Only Shift shows up

Comment: In that case it might be a keyboard or keyboard firmware issue and not one in macOS.

Comment: I would also say that this is hardware problems, but if [ button working, it shouldnt be the keyboard.

Comment: The keyboard uses a matrix of connections and detects where the shorts are to find out the keys that were pressed. If something is wrong with that matrix or with the interpretation (the keyboard controller), individual keys might work, but some combinations don't. Maybe there is a firmware update? Or a keyboard reset method.

Comment: I've tried to download newest firmware from apple website, but it told me, that i have the newest version already. Also did a reset.
I think Im gonna take this keyboard to some apple maintenance shop

Comment: Good idea. Maybe they can test it with another device and see if the problem persists